# Free and non-free Dirac's particles

Tags: quantum-mechanics, special-relativity, dirac-equation, interactions, plane-wave

In trying to understand evolution of Dirac particle in relativistic QM (not QFT) I have following guess that I don't know I'm correct or wrong? edited after
solution of akhmeteli:

It is well known that every solution of free Dirac's equation could be decomposed to
4-dimentional plane waves whose momentum and energy satisfy relativistic energy equation.
But what about such decompostion of Dirac's field when it is in interation with some thing say
electromagnetic field? (I'm ignoring spin because I think it don't break such decomposition we need if I'm right.)
if it could be done then it satisfies free Dirac's equation not Dirac's equation containing interaction.
on the other hand I think physically we should have such decomposition because in every time within interaction
we could measure momentum of electron and that is we make Dirac's field to collapse to free state electron with definite momentum
that is plane wave solution of free Dirac's field.

Answer (score 0):

When it is "plane waves" in the wording of your question, then your guess does not look correct. Indeed, let us consider some solution of the "non-free" Dirac equation (e.g., the Dirac equation in electromagnetic field). This solution can be developed in a 4D Fourier integral, and the coefficients at the plane waves will only depend on the 4-momentum (and spin projections). Perhaps you had in mind decomposition of a solution into plane wave solutions of the free Dirac equation (such plane waves satisfy a certain relation between energy and momentum).

Comment: Thanks. Is there a place where I can read the proof of the statement you said? @akhmeteli

Comment: @moshtaba : The proof can be difficult, depending on assumptions on the solution (for example, theory of distributions may be needed), but it is just multi-dimensional Fourier transform (see, e.g., A. Vretblad, Fourier Analisis and its Applications, Chapter 9. There are no proofs for the multi-dimensional case there though. I am sure you will be able to find a proof elsewhere, but, judging by your question, the proof may be difficult for you).